# App crashes after installing a Xamarin-Forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crash

I have 3 self-written apps on my phone. 2 written with Xamarin.Android and one written with Xamarin.Forms. But there is a big problem. It always work only 2 or 1 app depending on which of the 3 apps was installed last. If one of the two Xamarin.Android apps was installed last, then both Android apps work. The Forms App, however, crashes immediately. Same the other way around. If the Forms app was installed last, it works fine. The two Android apps crash immediately.

Is there any reason for that? Are the frameworks not compatible?

Comment: read log form  tools > Android > devicelog

Comment: There are a lot System.DllNotFoundExceptions. So when a Xamarin.Android app was installed it removes nessersary dlls for Xamarin.Forms. Also the other way around. How to avoid this?

Comment: do you use linker ?

Comment: If you mean the linking option in 'Android Options': No

Comment: Okay I did it. I just had to uncheck 'Use Shared Runtime' in the Android Options for all three apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to install the apk from Debug folder.

Steps that worked for me:
 - Disable "Use Shared Runtime"
 - In Advanced Settings, Select supported architecture

Check the screenshot if not clear

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying a debug apk into the same device, with different Runtimes, when the apk is installed will remove the previous / override. So, you will need to: disable Shared Runtime, or make sure the dependencies are all the same in all the applications

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio then Check "Application output" with release on device.

In Application Output you can see if any exception is causing problem..